# Pfaffian And Determinant

Tags: determinant, algebraic-combinatorics, pfaffian

I am working in tilings using Pfaffian. There is a basic property, namely:

Let $ B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Let
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
0    & B\\
-B^T & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

then 
$$\operatorname{Pf}(A)=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2} }\det(B)$$
thanks for the hints. 
The property $\operatorname{Pf}(A)^2=\det(A)$ gives me $\operatorname{Pf}(A)=\pm\sqrt{\det(A)}$. With the $n$ column exchanges we get
$$\det (A) = (-1)^n\det \begin{pmatrix}
B    & 0\\
 0& -B^T 
\end{pmatrix}=(-1)^n\det(B)\cdot (-1)^n\det (B^T)$$

But somewhere along I just miss something important :(

Comment: $A$ is skew-symmetric. What's the problem?

Comment: As noted in the previous comment, $A$ is skew-symmetric, which shows that $\mathrm{Pf}\,A$ can only be $\pm \mathrm{det}\, B$. To figure out the sign, look at the sign with which some particular product of elements of $B$ (say, $b_{11}b_{22}\ldots b_{nn}$) appears in the pfaffian and in the determinant.